# can i use intel app framework and phonegap together to build android apps

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

i am new to **Phonegap** & Intel app framework. i was build some simple android applications using **Phonegap** and **jQuery Mobile** but i want to use UI of **Intel App Framework** in application.

can i use **Intel App Framework** and **Phonegap** both together to build android apps?
i am not using **Phonegap Build** to deploy app. i deploy it using **Eclipse**.

if this is not possible then can i use **Intel XDK** for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use phonegap with Intel App Framework, but using it with jq mobile is totally pointless. You either use pg + appframework or pg + jq mobi.